# Calculus - generalized integral

Tags: calculus

Consider the convergence of the following generalized integral: $$I=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\sin x}{x^\alpha+\sin x}\,\mathrm dx$$

Let $\displaystyle{I=\int_0^1\frac{\sin x}{x^\alpha+\sin x}\,\mathrm dx + \int_1^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x^\alpha+\sin x}\,\mathrm dx=I_1+I_2}$.

If $\alpha\geq1$, then $I_1$ and $I_2$ are convergent (by Dirichlet's test for convergence).

If $0<\alpha<1$, I don't know the way to do with $I_2$ but I know $I_1$ is convergent.

How should I determine convergence of $I_2$ ($0<\alpha<1$)?

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\frac{\sin x}{x^\alpha +\sin x}-\frac{\sin x}{x^\alpha}=-\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{2\alpha}+x^\alpha\sin x}$$

The right hand side is non-positive in $[1,\infty)$ and so can be compared to $-\frac{1}{x^{2\alpha}}$ whose integral in $[1,\infty)$ is convergent if and only if $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$. Since $\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha}}dx$ converges for all $\alpha>0$, we get that the original integral converges if and only if $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I understood